Problems Sending Data From Python to MySQL
I’m having problems with the connector engine from SQLAlchemy connecting to MySQL.
The database and table I want to insert into are already created in MySQL.
I keep getting an AttributeError: ‘Engine’ object has no attribute ‘cursor’
I have the web scraped data into a dataframe and I'm trying to send it into MySQL.
And the error occurs when I run:
df.to_sql(‘ibm_stock_webdata’, con=engine, if_exists=‘replace’, index = True)
I saved all credentials in an .env file:
load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")
mysql_user = os.getenv("MYSQL_USER")
mysql_password = os.getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD")
mysql_host = os.getenv("MYSQL_HOST")
mysql_database = os.getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE")

if not api_key:
    raise ValueError("API key not found. Make sure your .env file is set up correctly")

if not all([mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_host, mysql_database]):
    raise ValueError("MySQL connection details not found. Make sure your .env file is set up correctly.")

Created a connector string:
mysql_connection_string = f'mysql+pymysql://{mysql_user}:{mysql_password}@{mysql_host}/{mysql_database}'

Created the engine:
engine = create_engine(mysql_connection_string)

The error occurs in this code block:
stock_data.to_sql('ibm_stock_webdata', con=engine, index=True, if_exists='replace')

[Code Block With Errors](https://i.sstatic.net/MBHaGFVp.png)
